# Calculate VAT in SQL (Doctrine)

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to make filters for shop i'm working on and i have a problem.
i have 2 fields 'price' which is a net price and vatrate which is the tax rate stored for example as '22' which is 22%. In my function i tried to use having clause to make calculations on the query side, here's how i tried to do this:

```
public function getCategoryActiveProductsQueryBuilder(CategoryInterface $category = null, $filter = null, $option = null) {
    $queryBuilder = $this->getCategoryProductsQueryBuilder($category);
    $queryBuilder->leftJoin('p.variations', 'pv')
            ->andWhere('p.parent IS NULL')      // Limit to master products or products without variations
            ->andWhere('p.enabled = :enabled')
            ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->orX('pv.enabled = :enabled', 'pv.enabled IS NULL'))
            ->setParameter('enabled', true);

    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

    $pfrom = $request->query->get('pfrom');
    $pto = $request->query->get('pto');


    if (is_numeric($pfrom)) {

        $queryBuilder->groupBy('p.price')
                ->andHaving('p.price * (1 + ( p.vatRate / 100)) >= ' . $pfrom . '');
    }

    if (is_numeric($pto)) {

        $queryBuilder->groupBy('p.price')
                ->andHaving('p.price * (1 + ( p.vatRate / 100)) <= ' . $pto . '');
    }

  return $queryBuilder;
```

i'm not sure what's wrong but it gives me error

An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT DISTINCT p0_.id AS id0 FROM product__product p0_ LEFT JOIN media__media m1_ ON p0_.image_id = m1_.id LEFT JOIN media__gallery m2_ ON p0_.gallery_id = m2_.id LEFT JOIN product__product_category p3_ ON p0_.id = p3_.product_id LEFT JOIN product__product p4_ ON p0_.id = p4_.parent_id AND p4_.product_type IN ('m2m.ecommerce.product.cloths', 'm2m.ecommerce.product.shoes', 'm2m.ecommerce.product.women_shoes', 'm2m.ecommerce.product.accessories', 'm2m.ecommerce.product.wear_accessories') WHERE (p3_.category_id = ? AND p0_.parent_id IS NULL AND p0_.enabled = ? AND (p4_.enabled = ? OR p4_.enabled IS NULL)) AND p0_.product_type IN ('m2m.ecommerce.product.cloths', 'm2m.ecommerce.product.shoes', 'm2m.ecommerce.product.women_shoes', 'm2m.ecommerce.product.accessories', 'm2m.ecommerce.product.wear_accessories') GROUP BY p0_.price HAVING p0_.price * (1 + (p0_.vat_rate / 100)) >= 0 LIMIT 9 OFFSET 0' with params [16, 1, 1]:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'p0_.vat_rate' in 'having clause'

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: we need entity class file

Comment: Can you post the output of `show create table product__product`?